# TJvInspector - Get Property Values?

Tags: delphi, jedi

How do you get the value that has been entered into the JvInspector at runtime?

The Demo in `\..\jvcl\examples\JvInspector` shows how to add strings, by writing something like this (extract from the demo):

```
var
  FirstName: string;

implementation

procedure TfrmInspector.AddVarious;
var
  InspCat: TJvInspectorCustomCategoryItem;
begin
  TJvInspectorVarData.New(InspCat, 'First', TypeInfo(string), @FirstName).DisplayName := 'Copy of first name';
end;
```

I wanted to add a TColor property so I did this:

```
var
  FirstName: string;
  SomeColor: TColor;

implementation

procedure TfrmInspector.AddVarious;
var
  InspCat: TJvInspectorCustomCategoryItem;
begin
  TJvInspectorVarData.New(InspCat, 'First', TypeInfo(string), @FirstName).DisplayName := 'Copy of first name';
  TJvInspectorVarData.New(InspCat, 'SomeColor', TypeInfo(TColor), @SomeColor;
end;
```

This displays correctly but I cannot seem to get the value that is changed for SomeColor when selecting a new color from the dropdown list in the inspector.

I tried this:

```
procedure TfrmInspector.JvInspector1ItemValueChanged(Sender: TObject;
  Item: TJvCustomInspectorItem);
begin
  if (Item.Data <> nil) and (CompareText(Item.Data.Name, 'FirstName') = 0) then
    ShowMessage(Item.Data.AsString) //< works
  else if (Item.Data <> nil) and (CompareText(Item.Data.Name, 'SomeColor') = 0) then
    ShowMessage(ColorToString(TColor(Item.Data))); //< does not return correct value
end;
```

I don't normally use Jedi components but thought I would give them another chance but there seems to be little documentation, I looked on the Wiki page for OnItemValueChanged event: [http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvInspector.OnItemValueChanged](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvInspector.OnItemValueChanged) but again barely any information or help.

I am sure instead of trying to get `ColorToString(TColor(Item.Data))` I need to use `Item.Data.AsVariant` but I could be wrong, when I tried I got AV errors so I probably am totally wrong, nothing I ever do or try seems to work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Item.Data` property is an object reference of type `TJvCustomInspectorData`; type-casting it to `TColor` yields nonsense. `TColor` is an ordinal type, so use the `AsOrdinal` method just as the string code uses `AsString`:

```
ShowMessage(ColorToString(TColor(Item.Data.AsOrdinal)));
```

Alternatively, you should just be able to read from the global `SomeColor` variable you passed when you created the item in the first place.

Comment: Good stuff Rob I knew there would be a better way, and regarding the last comment you made I tried the variable way and reading `SomeColor` and that worked. For some reason I thought that global variable was only going to be read-only, I did not think to try it as I expected the result would be what I assigned to it earlier on. I feel really silly now, a perfect example of me over complicating things :)

Answer (score 0):

I found one way that works:

```
procedure TfrmInspector.JvInspector1ItemValueChanged(Sender: TObject;
  Item: TJvCustomInspectorItem);
var
  sVal: string;
begin
  if (Item.Data <> nil) then
  begin
    sVal := Item.DisplayValue;

    if (CompareText(Item.Data.Name, 'FirstName') = 0) then
      ShowMessage('FirstName Value: ' + sVal)
    else if (CompareText(Item.Data.Name, 'SomeColor') = 0) then
      ShowMessage('SomeColor Value: ' + sVal); //<can use StringToColor now
  end;
end;
```

Though probably not the best way I thought I would post it anyway.